# Copy data into another sheet, based on offset locations of selected cell

Tags: excel, offset, vba

I select a cell in Sheet 1. 
I am trying to save that cell location to then offset and copy the data 3 cells above into sheet 2 "A1", then back to sheet 1 and offset 4 cells down of that selected cell and copy the data into sheet 2 "C1".

I will be selecting a different cell each time I use this macro hence why it has to rotate around the current selected cell. I am only stuck with how save the selected cell location to then use it through the sub.

My solution:

```
Sheets("Income").Select
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Claim APR").Select
Range("D92").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("Income").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Claim APR").Select
Range("F93").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have currently.

Comment: I have managed a way to get what I want.

Comment: @James You can add your solution as an answer and accept it, this is a much better way to "close" a question.